# WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback failed. OperationStatus = 0x80004001

Tags: c++, windows, fingerprint, biometrics

I am trying to read fingerprints and save them using WBF.

I tried the sample code, however, I get an error code back. I am able to use the fingerprint reader to log into windows, but am unable to capture samples from it.

I am running Windows 10 on a Lenovo Yoga system, and VS 2015 Community.

This is what I get when I run my code:

Calling WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback
 Swipe the sensor ...

CaptureSampleCallback executing
 Swipe processed - Unit ID: 0
 WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback failed.  OperationStatus = 0x80004001

Press any key to exit...

Thank you!

Sample code:

```
HRESULT CaptureSampleWithCallback(BOOL bCancel)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle = NULL;

    // Connect to the system pool. 
    hr = WinBioOpenSession( 
            WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    // Service provider
            WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
            WINBIO_FLAG_RAW,            // Raw access
            NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
            0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
            WINBIO_DB_DEFAULT,          // Default database
            &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
            );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    // Capture a biometric sample asynchronously.
    wprintf_s(L"\n Calling WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback ");
    hr = WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback(
            sessionHandle,                  // Open session handle
            WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE,    // Intended use of the sample
            WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW,           // Sample format
            CaptureSampleCallback,          // Callback function
            NULL                            // Optional context
            );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback failed. ");
        wprintf_s(L"hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        goto e_Exit;
    }
    wprintf_s(L"\n Swipe the sensor ...\n");

    // Cancel the capture process if the bCancel flag is set.
    if (bCancel)
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n Starting CANCEL timer...");
        Sleep( 7000 );

        wprintf_s(L"\n Calling WinBioCancel\n");
        hr = WinBioCancel( sessionHandle );
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioCancel failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
            goto e_Exit;
        }
    }

    // Wait for the asynchronous capture process to complete 
    // or be canceled.
    hr = WinBioWait( sessionHandle );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioWait failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
    }

e_Exit:

    if (sessionHandle != NULL)
    {
        WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
        sessionHandle = NULL;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"\n Press any key to exit...");
    _getch();

    return hr;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The following function is the callback for WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback.
// The function filters the response from the biometric subsystem and 
// writes a result to the console window.
//
VOID CALLBACK CaptureSampleCallback(
    __in_opt PVOID CaptureCallbackContext,
    __in HRESULT OperationStatus,
    __in WINBIO_UNIT_ID UnitId,
    __in_bcount(SampleSize) PWINBIO_BIR Sample,
    __in SIZE_T SampleSize,
    __in WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL RejectDetail
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CaptureCallbackContext);

    wprintf_s(L"\n CaptureSampleCallback executing");
    wprintf_s(L"\n Swipe processed - Unit ID: %d", UnitId);

    if (FAILED(OperationStatus))
    {
        if (OperationStatus == WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n Bad capture; reason: %d\n", RejectDetail);
         }
        else
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioCaptureSampleWithCallback failed. ");
            wprintf_s(L" OperationStatus = 0x%x\n", OperationStatus);
        }
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"\n Captured %d bytes.\n", SampleSize);

e_Exit:

    if (Sample != NULL)
    {
        WinBioFree(Sample);
        Sample = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you debugged it?

Comment: @John3136 I tried to step into the function but it just hanges there, as soon as I enter my fingerprint and step into it again, it returns the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on google or with the SDK documentation what OperationStatus = 0x80004001 translates to? I am thinking you need to stop the windows service for the fingerprint before you embark on trying out the project you are developing on Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I did not try stopping the service. I was reading that as of Windows 10 build 1600 (or 1600+), those APIs would be disabled. Not sure. I ended up using their Universal App APIs for fingerprint authentication. However, I still want to be able to extract fingerprints to do some analysis on them. Will try stopping the service (whichever it is).